# C++ Qt скачка по http xml файла

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос такой. Можно ли по http скачать xml файл в буфер, открыть файл расположенный в буфере для чтения и распарсить его? Щас сделано так, приходится скачивать сам файл, располагать его в кталоге с проектоми там уже открывать через QFile для чтения и дальнейшего его парсинга. Как будет выглядеть код скачивания xml с сайта  в буфер и начало его парсинга?

Comment: Скачайте его в `char []` а лучше `wchar_t []`, а в xml-парсере есть ф-ция loadXML вместо load которая грузит с стоки (по крайней мере в win)

Comment: Что то не могу найти в Qt функцию loadXml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

план мероприятий:)

1. Добавьте QNetworkAccessManager в include и как поле класса. пусть его имя будет `manager`.
2. Подпишитесь на finisherd

   connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &loader::finished);
3. В нужном месте добавьте запрос

   QNetworkRequest r(QUrl("http://url-to-podcast"));
   manager.get(r);
4. в finished пишем обработку

   ```
   void loader::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
   {
       // так как reply это QIODevice, а xml ридер умеет с него загружаться, то можно прямо так
       QXmlStreamReader xml(reply);
       // не забыть почистить ресурсы
       reply->deleteLater();
       // читаем поэлементно наш xml
       while (!xml.atEnd() && !xml.hasError())
       {
           QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xml.readNext();
           if (token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument)
              continue;
           // если это начало нового элемента
           if (token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
           {
               // и это item
               if (xml.name() == "item")
                   // распарсим и выведем!
                   qDebug() << parseOneItem(xml);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

ну и собственно сам парсер элемента

```
QString Foo::parseOneItem(QXmlStreamReader &xml)
{
    QString s;
    xml.readNext();
    while (!(xml.tokenType() == QXmlStreamReader::EndElement && xml.name() == "item")) {
        if (xml.tokenType() == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
        {
            if (xml.name() == "title") {
                xml.readNext();
                QString t = xml.text().toUtf8();
                s += QString("title %1").arg(t);
            }
            if (xml.name() == "link") {
                xml.readNext();
                QString t = xml.text().toUtf8();
                s += QString("link %1").arg(t);
            }
        }

        xml.readNext();
    }
    return s;
}
```

если кто не догадался, то парсятся xml от подкастов

Answer (score 0):

Если это нужно для пользовательского интерфейса, порекомендую вам использовать QML, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html